# Modx. Установка приложений из менеджера пакетов. Установила modalConsole, но не знаю, как его найти

Tags: modx

У меня такая проблема. Установила приложение modalconsole из менеджера пакетов ModX, но теперь не знаю, как его запустить. В демонстрационном видеоролике виден значок приложения в верхней панели в админке, но у меня нет такого значка, и я не знаю, ни как добавить его, ни как запустить консоль хоть откуда-нибудь. Как запустить приложение и добавить его значок в быстрый доступ?

Comment: какая версия MODX?

Comment: @AntonTarasov 2.8.3